# Convert a string into mathematical function of x :f(x)?

Tags: android, math, android-library

Hello I'm a beginner in Android programming.
I'm working on a graphic calculator but i still have the problem of converting the function to math

For example :

```
y=cos(x^2)-ln(x)
```

should look like

```
y=Math.cos(x*x) - Math.log(x)
```

And than we plot it.

Thank You

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `still have the problem` - what is the problem? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to convert a String to a float or double?

```
String input = "3.14";
float x = Float.parseFloat(input);
```

This code converts the String "3.14" into a float. You can use this float in the function you described in the question.

EDIT:
If you want to convert the full function String into Java code, you should limit the input to buttons. For example, add a button named "Cos", and remember in the code the user wants to use the Cosinus function. Then the user enters a value, and presses "Enter". The code knows it should use the cosinus function, and x is the value entered in an EditText. That value should be parsed using Float.parseFloat().

Comment: Thank you
I create for each function a button but my problem is how to convert a string to mathematical expression containing x(double)

Comment: Have a look at the code in my answer. It converts the String "3.14" into a float. You can use that float in the mathematical expression.

Comment: but my string can contain cos(x) or ln(x+1) ....... how can we convert it